# three.js Large Plane Low FPS

Tags: three.js

I have a problem with three.js where having a plane with a large texture close to the camera causes serious FPS drop using the CanvasRenderer. The further away the camera, the better the fps.

Code is here: http://pastebin.com/eZgnewa1

map.jpg is a 2048x2048 screenshot from google maps.

I've tried changing the dimensions of pretty much everything including the plane size and segments amounts of the PlaneGeometry, but nothing seems to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using `CanvasRenderer`. Chances are what you're trying to do is a bit too much for poor `CanvasRenderer`.

PS. If you can share a working live link it'll be easier to see what's going on.